# Why my Toggle button requires double tap to Unselect if it is Selected on Activity onCreate.?

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I have created two toogle buttons from `Button` class.

Criteria

1) atleast one of the both must be selected or both can be selected.

Works fine,

But small issue,

**When Activity is loaded with buttons in selected state, unselecting it for the first time takes double tap, why?**

Consider my example below, where both the buttons are selected.

*This is my Global declaration.*

```
private boolean isMaleSelected = false;
private boolean isFemaleSelected = false;
```

*This is my initialization in onCreate(),*

```
//Selecting both buttons
isMaleSelected = true;
isFemaleSelected = true;
```

*These are my two buttons, male and female*

```
 maletoggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isFemaleSelected) {

                    view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
                isMaleSelected = view.isSelected();
                    if (view.isSelected()) {
                        view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_textview));
                        ((Button) view).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    } else {
                        view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_textview));
                        ((Button) view).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
femaletoggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(isMaleSelected) {
                        view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
                    isFemaleSelected = view.isSelected();
                        if (view.isSelected()) {
                            view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_textview));
                            ((Button) view).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        } else {
                            view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_textview));
                            ((Button) view).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: please check my edited solution

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below solution...might it can help you

```
    public class Example extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;

    private Boolean b1,b2,b3 =  false;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Button1:
            if(b1)
            {             
               b1 = false;         
               button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_textview));
               button1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));  

            else
             {
              b1 = true;         
              button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_textview));
              button1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

            }

            break;

           case R.id.Button2:
            if(b2)
            {             
               b2 = false;         
               button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_textview));
               button2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));  

            else
             {
              b2 = true;         
              button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_textview));
              button2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

              }

            break;
       case R.id.Button3:
            if(b3)
            {             
               b3 = false;         
               button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_textview));
               button3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));  

            else
             {
              b3 = true;         
              button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_textview));
              button3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

              }

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
       }
     }
```

Comment: I am using button class, and not toggle button class, my online problem is it takes double tap to unselect it, if its selected on Activity OnCreate,  then after that i can select/unselect it with a single tap. hope my question is clear

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in below line

```
view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
```

change this line in maletoggle click to

```
view.setSelected(!isFemaleSelected);
```

and in femaletoggle click to

```
view.setSelected(!isMaleSelected);
```

Comment: With this, i can unselect it in one tap on Activity load, but then i cannot change its state anymore

Comment: Are you trying to implement checkbox or toggle button? As i can understand you are trying to build toggle button. Toggle button state changes when you select another button from toggle button group. Hence you need to click male to select male and you need to select female to select feamle